# Amazon MWS : Errors with new 2013 ListOrders API

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-mws

I am upgrading my Amazon orders download script from:
$serviceUrl = "https://mws-eu.amazonservices.com/Orders/2011-01-01"
to 
$serviceUrl = "https://mws-eu.amazonservices.com/Orders/2013-09-01"

Some of the parameters have changed from arrays to strings.

Using ListOrdersSample.php I am trying to only download Unshipped and PartiallyShipped orders but I am having difficulty formatting the variable.

In the scratchpad I see:

OrderStatus.Status.1=Unshipped
OrderStatus.Status.2=PartiallyShipped

I have tried:

```
//$orderStatuses='OrderStatus.Status.1=Unshipped,OrderStatus.Status.2=PartiallyShipped';
// $orderStatuses='Unshipped:PartiallyShipped';
// $orderStatuses='Unshipped&PartiallyShipped';
// $orderStatuses= (array("Unshipped", "PartiallyShipped"));
$orderStatuses='Unshipped';
$request->setOrderStatus($orderStatuses);
```

All versions of separators seem to fail with the similar error:

> Caught Exception: 1 validation error detected: Value
>   '[Unshipped&PartiallyShipped]' at 'orderStatus' failed to satisfy
>   constraint: Member must satisfy constraint: [Member must satisfy enum
>   value set: [Unfulfillable, PartiallyShipped, PendingAvailability,
>   Shipped, Pending, InvoiceUnconfirmed, Canceled, Unshipped]]

The only one to work is the uncommented Unshipped on it's own then I get the error:

> Caught Exception: Unshipped and PartiallyShipped should be used
>   together when filtering by OrderStatus.  You cannot use one and not
>   the other.

I have a similar problem trying to list multiple marketplaceids.

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 3):

I finally got it to work. If anyone is interested, the format for multi item strings is:

```
$marketplaceIdList=(array('A1F83G8C2ARO7P','A13V1IB3VIYZZH','A1PA6795UKMFR9','APJ6JRA9NG5V4','A1RKKUPIHCS9HS','ATVPDKIKX0DER')); 
$request->setMarketplaceId($marketplaceIdList);

$orderStatuses=(array('Unshipped','PartiallyShipped'));  
$request->setOrderStatus($orderStatuses);

invokeListOrders($service, $request);
```